# UICollectionView crashes when scrolling past first row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an array of objects that I'm populating the label text of a custom UICollectionViewCell with. When I start the app, the cells show up fine, but as soon as I scroll past the first row of cells, the app crashes. I've enabled zombies, and the last line in the debug before crashing is:

```
*** -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x174233be0
```

Here is the code returning each cell:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BadgeCell";
    BadgeCell *cell = (BadgeCell *)[badgeCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Badge *cellData = dataArray[indexPath.row];
    [cell.titleLabel setText:cellData.badgeName];
    return cell;
}
```

EDIT: code in BadgeCell:

```
@synthesize titleLabel;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        NSArray *arrayOfViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BadgeCell" owner:self options:nil];
        if ([arrayOfViews count] < 1)
        {
            return nil;
        }
        if (![[arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]])
        {
            return nil;
        }
        self = [arrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've got a dangling pointer for some reason. Can you share the code in `Badge` and possibly even `BadgeCell`? Perhaps there's something wrong with reusing those cells and the reuse pool. Maybe even something with the cell data itself.

Comment: I think you'll need a few more lines from the stack trace to decipher this, the call to CFString made indirectly.   Is the (NSString *) badgeName property in your model retained properly (strong) ??

Comment: That was the problem, @Jef. The badgeName was assign, not strong. Thanks so much. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your model is not retaining this property (NSString*)badgeName  properly, is the retain policy set to strong (or copy, which might be more appropriate)?

Comment: This was the problem. What was happening was scrolling past the first row would deallocate the NSStrings being used to populate the cell's title text.